# Facebook data, how to put it in props?

Tags: javascript, facebook, reactjs, flux

I am trying to put the response from Facebook in the props of my app so I can have them available everywhere. So far, what I am doing is saving the data that I need in the localStorage, which I guess is not the proper way.

Actually the userID its been saved in the props but not with the proper flow. At the end of the post you will see the flow I have, and the flow I need.

Look at my code

```
// LIBRARY
import React from 'react';
import connectToStores from 'alt-utils/lib/connectToStores';

const { PropTypes } = React;

import AppActions from '../../actions/AppActions';
import AppStore from '../../stores/AppStore';

// @connectToStores
export default class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const _this = this;
    _this.checkSession();
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <HtmlHeaderTags />
        <Header />
        <div className='main-content'>
          {this.props.children}
        </div>
        <Footer />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

App.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.node
};

App.prototype.initFB = function(callback){

  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : window.facebook_id,
      cookie     : true,  // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml      : true,  // parse social plugins on this page
      version    : 'v2.5' // use version 2.1
    });
    callback();
  }.bind(this);

  // Load the SDK asynchronously
  (function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js';
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

}

App.prototype.checkFBSession = function() {

  FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    if (response.status === 'connected') {

      // HERE I AM SETTING THE USERID IN THE LOCALSTORAGE
      localStorage.setItem('userID', response.authResponse.userID);

    } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
      // the user is logged in to Facebook,
      // but has not authenticated your app
      console.error('Rejected (not_authorized)');
    } else {
      // the user isn't logged in to Facebook.
      console.error('Rejected (not logged in)');
      localStorage.removeItem('userID');
    }
  });
}

App.prototype.callServer = function(opts){

  var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.open(opts.type, opts.url);
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
      if(xmlhttp.status == 200){
        opts.success(xmlhttp.response);
      }else{
        opts.error(JSON.parse(xmlhttp.response));
      }
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.send(opts);
}

App.prototype.checkSession = function() {

  const _this = this;

  _this.callServer({
    url : '/api/me',
    type : 'GET',
    success(res){
      console.log(res);
    }, error(error){
      console.error(error);
    }
  });

  _this.initFB(function() {

    _this.checkFBSession(function(response){
      console.log(response);
    }, function(error){
      console.log(error);
    });
  });

}

App.prototype.displayName = 'App';
```

There is where everything begins. In `App.prototype.checkFBSession` I am setting the userID in the localStorage. Then I have my action and my store for this, look:

**the action**

```
import { createActions } from 'alt-utils/lib/decorators';
import alt from '../alt';

@createActions(alt)
class AppActions {
  constructor() {
    this.generateActions(
      'checkFBSession'
    );
  }
}
export default alt.createActions(AppActions);
```

**and my store**

```
import AppActions from '../actions/AppActions';

import alt from '../alt';
import { createStore, bind } from 'alt-utils/lib/decorators';


@createStore(alt)
class AppStore {

  static displayName = 'AppStore';

  constructor () {
    this.state = {
      facebookProp : localStorage.getItem('userID') || '',
    };
  }

  @bind(AppActions.checkFBSession)
  checkFBSession () {
    this.setState({
      facebookProp : localStorage.getItem('userID') || {}
    });
  }
```

And here is the component where I am requiring the userID

```
import React from 'react';
import connectToStores from 'alt-utils/lib/connectToStores';

import AppActions from '../../actions/AppActions';
import AppStore from '../../stores/AppStore';

@connectToStores
export default class Header extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  static getStores () {
    return [
      AppStore
    ];
  }

  static getPropsFromStores () {
    return {
      ...AppStore.getState()
    };
  }

  render () {

    let displayUserId;

    displayUserId = this.props.facebookProp ?
      {this.props.facebookProp} :
      <Button bsSize="xsmall" bsStyle="primary">{'Sign in'}</Button>;

    return (
      <Navbar staticTop>            
       {displayUserId}
      </Navbar>
    );
  }
};

Header.prototype.displayName = 'Header';

export default Header;
```

So basically what I need to know is:

Where to put the Facebook login code in order to send the data from the response to the store.

Because what I am doing now is: loading the app, call Facebook functions on componentDidMount, storing the response from Facebook in the localStorage and then spreading that data to the components I need.

The flow I need is similar to that, but I need to the userID from Facebook in the stores and actions and not from the parent component.

So what are your recommendations?

I am also open to suggestions on how to do is as this is my first time working with a Facebook login, I am just a junior dev.

Comment: Why are you using `prototype` when you can define the functions in the class?

Comment: @taylorc93 that is actually the way I saw it in a tutorial.

Comment: Your component should store everything in your store using actions. If the store then chooses to use `localStorage` that's fine, but the component should know nothing about that.

Comment: @MatthewHerbst that is ok, I get it, but, can you help me with piece of code? I don't how to adapt my code to those requirements.

Comment: I'm not familiar with vanilla `Flux` or `localStorage`. I recommend taking a look `Redux` or `Reflux`. It will make doing `Flux`-like things much simpler